# Using static in translation unit containing main function

Tags: c, static, header, declaration

Is it a good idea to declare variables and functions as static in the C file which contains the main function? I'm thinking that it does not make a difference in practice.

Update: If modular programming is adhered to, each function and non-local variable which is not a part of a module's interface is made static. The main module, however, has no interface (for obvious reasons) so using static doesn't solve any problem because there is none.

Comment: No context - no possible answer. If you do not have any other translation units it is not needed. If object is used only in one translation unit static is OK. As a workaround for defining data in the .h file - it is not OK.

Comment: If you want to make explicit that these functions and variables may not be used by other C-modules, then yes.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie If you adhere to modular programming, all exported identifiers are declared in a header file but the main C file (typically) has no associated header file.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom yes, but of course that is only a convention. I don't think the file/compilation unit containing the `main` needs a special rule - the same considerations that are valid for all other files still apply.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom When you use `static` at global space you tell the compiler that this variable/function is only used in this TLU/file. What has the exporting of declarations into a header to do with declaring a variable or function with the `static` qualifier? I can't follow your concerns.

Answer (score 2):

If you define "global variables" (i.e. variables at file scope) without the keyword `static`, then these identifiers will have [external linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration), which means that they will be visible to other translation units. In that case, they will interfere with equally named identifiers defined there, if they also have external linkage. This usually leads to a linker error. This does not depend on whether the definition is in a header file, a `.c`-file, or the `.c`-file containing also function `main`.

Simple rule: If an identifier shall be visible only to the current translation unit, define it as `static`. If it shall be visible to other translation units as well, don't use `static`.

Comment: And I suggest applying that rule even in projects that have only one TU (and I wonder whether this is what the OP had in mind).  Then you're covered in the event that it later expands to include others.  I would rather discover a need to converted a `static` variable or function to `extern` than the other way around.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Speaking in the context of modular programming, we declare static functions and static non-local variables to prevent potential name clashes when a module is used by another module. However, the entry point module containing the main function is a pure client module which is not used by any other module, so therefor I reason that making functions and non-local variables static in the entry point module is not strictly necessary.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom, C does not have any sense of a unidirectional "used by" relationship.  Those identifiers declared with external linkage in the TU containing `main()` have just as much potential to clash with identifiers declared in other TUs as do those declared anywhere else.

Comment: Or if you want to look at translation units as modules (also not really a C concept), then you must accept that the TU containing `main()` is a module, too.

Answer (score 0):

> "If you adhere to modular programming, all exported identifiers are declared in a header file but the main C file (typically) has no associated header file."

First of all, not all either implicitly (by omission of any storage-class specifier) or explicitly `extern` declared objects/functions *have to* be declared in headers for other *translation units* (TLUs) /files, except the one where `main()` is, too.

In fact, it is even only a convention to split a program that way to separate program parts.

Second, You *can* also put the declarations of `static` objects into a header file.

With this regard, you can do whatever you like to as it does not make a change other than to declare the linkage. If you want to not use specific objects/functions in other TLUs /files declare it with `static`. If not, you need to omit it.

Everything discussed here is a matter of one's own coding style and opinion and is neither good nor bad, although it is maybe not seen as good practice to declare `static` objects/functions in header files.

> "I'm thinking that it does not make a difference in practice."

The only difference is the different linkage. Else it doesn't make a difference indeed.

That being said, the most obvious case to omit a specific `static` declaration is of course when your program is only consisted of a single TLU.

But again, if you declare things `static` here is a matter of your own choice to code.

Comment: One absolutely can put `static` declarations into header files, yes.  But it is rarely a good idea, it frequently constitutes a mistake, and even when it is intentional and correct, it tends to be confusing.  It is in the category of things one *can* do, but shouldn't.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I like to be as less opinion-based as possible (especially for this kind of questions where opinions are almost entirely ground-based), but I took it into it.